# Xcode Error - missing required architecture i386 in file

Tags: ios, string, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to compile a demo project from Unity in Xcode (it's actually a tutorial on a new Augmented Reality platform that integrates with Unity called String) and getting this error:

```
ignoring file libiPhone-lib.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

I've researched this a little, and it seems to be some sort of issue with what version of iOS you're deploying too, but I'm not sure. Regardless, I've tried to deploy to different versions, and they all result in this error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some research and it seems Unity for iPhone doesn't deploy on simulator. It only works on device or in the Unity editor. Check out this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/20774/problem-with-linking-internal-xcode-frameworks.html). Hope it helps.